# Importing Several Raster Layers, Doing Manipulations and Exporting The Newly Saved Rasters

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I have the following code:

```
src_ds = gdal.Open("/home/usr/Desktop/RasterFolder/Name.tif")
if src_ds is None: 
    print 'Unable to open %s' % src_filename
    sys.exit(1) 
myarray = np.array(src_ds.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray())
rows = src_ds.RasterYSize 
cols = src_ds.RasterXSize
BufferDistance = 15 
IndexingSquare = 2*BufferDistance + 1
i,j = np.ogrid[:IndexingSquare,:IndexingSquare] 
struct = ((i-BufferDistance)**2 + (j-BufferDistance)**2 <=BufferDistance**2+1)  
forests_buffered = ndimage.binary_dilation(myarray, structure=struct)       
driver = src_ds.GetDriver()
outDs = driver.Create("/home/usr/Desktop/Buffers/Name_NEW.tif", cols, rows, 1, GDT_Int32)
if outDs is None: 
    print 'Could not create .tif file'
    sys.exit(1)

outBand = outDs.GetRasterBand(1)
outData = forests_buffered 
#Write the data 
outBand.WriteArray(outData,0,0)
#Flush data to disk
outBand.FlushCache()
#geo-reference the image 
outDs.SetGeoTransform(src_ds.GetGeoTransform())
outDs.SetProjection(src_ds.GetProjection())
del outData
```

It inputs a raster file, creates a buffer with a certain buffer distance and then exports the new raster with the added buffer as a new .tiff file. I have all my rasters in a directory:

```
rasterDir = "/home/usr/Desktop/RasterFolder/"
```

What I need to do is apply the buffering using the code above to all the rasters in the RasterFolder (in an automated fashion) and save the outputs into a new output directory:

```
outputDir = "/home/usr/Desktop/Buffers/"
```

Could you give me a suggestion how to do this in the most computationally efficient way? Essentially, I want to create a function which loops through the files in the RasterFolder, applies the buffering and saves the buffered rasters in the output directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could use something like the following (*untested*) which uses the [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) function to search for rasters in a given directory (you may need to `import glob`):

```
def function():    
    myarray = np.array(src_ds.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray())
    rows = src_ds.RasterYSize 
    cols = src_ds.RasterXSize
    BufferDistance = 15 
    IndexingSquare = 2*BufferDistance + 1
    i,j = np.ogrid[:IndexingSquare,:IndexingSquare] 
    struct = ((i-BufferDistance)**2 + (j-BufferDistance)**2 <=BufferDistance**2+1)  
    forests_buffered = ndimage.binary_dilation(myarray, structure=struct)       
    driver = src_ds.GetDriver()  
    outDs = driver.Create("/home/usr/Desktop/Buffers/" + "NEW_" + fname, cols, rows, 1, GDT_Int32)
    if outDs is None: 
        print 'Could not create .tif file'
        sys.exit(1)
    outBand = outDs.GetRasterBand(1)
    outData = forests_buffered 
    #Write the data 
    outBand.WriteArray(outData,0,0)
    #Flush data to disk
    outBand.FlushCache()
    #geo-reference the image 
    outDs.SetGeoTransform(src_ds.GetGeoTransform())
    outDs.SetProjection(src_ds.GetProjection())
    del outData

os.chdir("/home/usr/Desktop/RasterFolder/")
for fname in glob.glob("*.tif"):
    src_ds = gdal.Open(fname)
    if src_ds is None: 
        print 'Unable to open %s' % src_filename
        sys.exit(1)
    else:
        function()
```